# RxJava2 | Chaining nested Completables with .andThen()

Tags: rx-java2

I have a "big" completable that does some error checking, and then does a two processing steps.

It looks like this:

```
// someProcessorClass
public Completable checkAndProcessFile(InputStream file, ...) {
    return checkHeaders(file, ...).andThen(processFile(file, ...));
}

private Completable checkHeaders(InputStream file, ...) {
    // checks the first line for the right headers
    // ...
    if(firstLineIsGood) {
        return Completable.complete();
    }
    return Completable.error(new Error('bad headers');   
}

private Completable processFile(file, ...) {
    return writeFile(file).andThen(writeMetadata(...));
}
```

What I want to do is for the `Completable` to break on the first `Completable checkHeaders()`, but instead, what seems to happen is `writeFile()` occurs regardless of whether there is an error or not.  The `writeMetadata()` does not get called.

So it seems like `processFile()` is acting eager to order to evaluate the the `Completable`.  I tried wrapping the second half in a `Completable.fromCallable()`, but then that requires an inner subscribe like so, which seems... not the right way to do it.

```
private Completable processFile(file, ...) {
    return Completable.fromCallable(()-> {
        return writeFile(file).andThen(writeMetadata(...)).subscribe();
    }
}
```

So my question is, is there a way to chain `Completables` in a lazy way?  Kind of like `flatMap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I understand (newbie here),

What I thought I was doing is

`checkHeaders.andThen(writeFile).andThen(writeMetadata)`

But by wrapping `writeFile.andThen(writeMetadata)` within another Completable (`processFile`), rxJava treated it more like

`checkHeaders.andThen((writeFile.andThen(writeMetadata))`

where it starts evaluating the inner parenthesis first.

So by just chaining `.andThen()`, you get the expected result of the `Completable` breaking `onError`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide your `writeFile` and `writeMetadata`. But I think they may like:

```
public Completable writeFile(InputStream file) {
  try {
    // write file here
  } catch (IOException e) {
    return Completable.error(e);
  }
  return Completable.complete();
}
```

That is totally wrong usage. You should do your work in `Completable`, not just return a `Completable`. The right usage is

```
public Completable writeFile(InputStream file) {
  return Completable.fromAction(() -> {
    // write file here
  });
}
```

Comment: Uh, yeah `processFile` and `writeMetadata` both are full functions that I'd didn't expand on, both make separate network requests.  I should've communicated more clearly.  Thanks though.